# The efficiency of a specific while loop

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm making a program for a school project and within the program, the user makes a decision. to make sure the user inputs a valid input. i want to know if using a while loop like this is efficient. it is be contained within a function that would be used multiple times. i did this as this function will be called and the returned value will be stored in a variable. this is for a command line programme:

```
    def user_choice(): 
       while True:
            choice = input("choose \'a\' or '\b\':")
            if choice == "a" or choice == "b":
                return choice
            else:
                print("not a valid input")
```

Comment: Very inefficient. Why are you waiting on a very slow bag of water to respond each loop? (Just kidding. Seems efficient enough.)

Comment: loops are useful for multiple iterations but it sound like you are validating a single decision. If so, you don't need a loop; just use the conditional statement by itself.

Comment: @AnthonyRGray, it validates a single input, and the loop's purpose is to keep asking for input until it gets a valid one.

Comment: you don't need a loop for that, @TigerhawkT3. Just return false and set focus to the field, with maybe an alert to prompt the user for valid input.

Comment: "set focus to the field" @AnthonyRGray . Uh, I suspect this is for a command-line/IDLE/ipython thing, so there is no field and this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: And what led you to believe that this is for a GUI program rather than for a simple command-line program?

Comment: he's using Javascript, @TigerhawkT3.

Comment: Just about the only thing I'd change, btw, is allowing for a little bit of error. Maybe accepting "A" and "B", and also stripping whitespace off of input.

Comment: Where does it say JavaScript?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it is for a command line programme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of raw machine efficiency, your algorithm is perfectly acceptable. The bottleneck is the user's input. It only goes through the loop once per input, so the actual execution of that code is basically instantaneous. Some programs will use a loop to continuously check some condition as fast as the computer can manage, and that is indeed suboptimal (eats up a CPU core).

In terms of good coding style, your algorithm is perfectly acceptable as well. Using a `while True` (or `while 1`) with a `return` on a valid input is very common and easily understood to any reader.

I would suggest some slight modifications like `if choice.lower().strip() in ('a', 'b'):` instead of `if choice == "a" or choice == "b":` as noted in a comment, but that's just to make it a bit more robust in the face of messy user input. Also, you don't need to escape quotes unless they're of the type that encloses the string, so you can do `input("choose 'a' or 'b':")` instead of `input("choose \'a\' or '\b\':")`.